# Cross Join to DQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to convert this I think simple mysql query into Doctrine dql, however, Im experience quite a struggle right now...

```
SELECT (c.prix-aggregates.AVG) AS test 
FROM immobilier_ad_blank c 
CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT AVG(prix) AS AVG 
     FROM immobilier_ad_blank) 
AS aggregates
```

Purpose of this: creating z-score. 
Original implementation coming from this question [Calculating Z-Score for each row in MySQL? (simple)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132613/calculating-z-score-for-each-row-in-mysql-simple)

I thought about creating an association within the entity, but I mean its not necessary, its only for stats.

Edit: Btw, I dont wanna use raw SQL, I will extract the "subquery" from another query builder expression using `getDQL`. Otherwise, I will have to rewrite my dynamic query builder to take in account for rawSQL.

Edit 2:
Tried this

```
$subQb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$subQb->addSelect("AVG(subC.prix) as AMEAN")
      ->from("MomoaIntegrationBundle:sources\Common", "subC");
$subDql = $subQb->getDQL();

$dql = "SELECT c.prix FROM MomoaIntegrationBundle:sources\Common c INNER JOIN ($subDql) AS aggregates";
```

Raw dql is:

```
SELECT c.prix FROM MomoaIntegrationBundle:sources\Common c INNER JOIN (SELECT AVG(subC.prix) as AMEAN FROM MomoaIntegrationBundle:sources\Common subC) AS aggregates
```

Getting this strange error:`line 0, col 70 near '(SELECT AVG(subC.prix)': Error: Class '(' is not defined.`

Edit 3:
I found kinda of a hawkish way to make it work but doctrine is stubborn with its implementation of entities and such and forgot that STATISTICS do NOT need ENTITIES !

```
     $subQb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $subQb->addSelect("AVG(subC.prix) as AMEAN")
            ->from("MomoaIntegrationBundle:sources\Common", "subC");

    $sql = "SELECT (c.prix-aggregates.sclr_0) AS test FROM immobilier_ad_blank c CROSS JOIN "
            . "({$subQb->getQuery()->getSQL()}) AS aggregates";
    $stm = $stm = $this->_em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();
    $data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

If you have a better solution, Im all ears ! I actually dislike this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex queries you might want to consider bypassing DQL and using a native query - especially since you don't need the result in an entity.

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();

$statement = $connection->prepare("
    select c.prix-aggregates, t1.avg 
    from immobilier_ad_blank
    cross join (
        select avg(prix) as avg
        from immobilier_ad_blank
    ) t1
");

$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Doctrine 2.4 it is possible to JOIN without using a defined association, for example:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN Items i WITH u.age = i.price
```

This one doesn't make any sense but you get the point.  The `WITH` keyword is absolutely required in this case, otherwise it is a syntax error, but you can just provide a dummy condition, like so:

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN Items i WITH 0 = 0
```

This essentially results in a cross join.  Whether this is a good idea in a given situation is a different question, but I have encountered situations where this was indeed very useful.