# How to calculate the z score after joining 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have joined three tables A, B, D using this query,

```
SELECT [A].ID, [A].Surname, [A].[Given Name], [B].[Pre-U Grade], [D ].[Total Score], [B].[score]
FROM ([A] LEFT JOIN [D] ON [A].ID = [D].[Student ID]) INNER JOIN [B-Results] ON [A].ID = [B].ID
WHERE ((([B].[Pre-U Grade])=IsNumeric([B]![Pre-U Grade])) AND (([D].[Total Score]) Is Not Null) AND (([A].Status) Not In ("REJECTED","OFFERED","WITHDRAWN"))) OR ((([B].[Pre-U Grade])>"0") AND (([D].[Total Score]) Is Not Null) AND (([A].Status) Not In ("REJECTED","OFFERED","WITHDRAWN")))
ORDER BY [D].[Date] DESC;
```

After joining the tables, the z-score for the 3 numerical columns needs to be calculated.

I came across this example 
[Calculating Z-Score for each row in MySQL? (simple)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132613/calculating-z-score-for-each-row-in-mysql-simple)

but i didnt know how to use the code given for my problem statement. Can someone kindly help me with this?

Comment: Can you give some example data in https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Are you using MS Access or MySQL? That query won't run on both.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    (pre-u_grade - AVG(pre-u_grade))/STD(pre-u_grade) z_pre-u_grade,
    (total_score- AVG(total_score))/STD(total_score) z_total_score,
    (score- AVG(score))/STD(score) z_score,
    (SELECT     
            a.id,     
            a.surname, 
            a.given_name,
            pre-u_grade,
            total_score,
            score
        FROM 
            a 
        LEFT JOIN  
            d 
        ON         
            a.id = d.student id) 
        INNER JOIN 
            b.results 
        ON
            a.id = b.id 
        WHERE      
             ( 
               ( b.pre-u_grade = ISNUMERIC(b ! pre-u_grade) 
                 AND  d.total score IS NOT NULL 
                 AND  a.status NOT IN ( "rejected", "offered", "withdrawn) ) 
             OR         
               ( b.pre-u_grade > 0 
                 AND d.total score ) IS NOT NULL 
                 AND a.status NOT IN ( "rejected", "offered", "withdrawn" ) )
              ) 
        ORDER BY   
            d.date DESC) result;
```

Try this.